# Download html in python?

Tags: python, html

I am trying to download the html of a page that is requested through a javascript action when you click a link in the browser. I can download the first page because it has a general URL:

```
http://www.locationary.com/stats/hotzone.jsp?hz=1
```

But there are links along the bottom of the page that are numbers (1 to 10). So if you click on one, it goes to, for example, page 2:

```
http://www.locationary.com/stats/hotzone.jsp?ACTION_TOKEN=hotzone_jsp$JspView$NumericAction&inPageNumber=2
```

When I put that URL into my program and try to download the html, it gives me the html of a different page on the website and I think it is the home page.

How can I get the html of this URL that uses javascript and when there is no specific URL?

Thanks.

Code:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import cookielib
import re

URL = ''

def load(url):

    data = urllib.urlencode({"inUserName":"email", "inUserPass":"password"})
    jar = cookielib.FileCookieJar("cookies")
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar))
    opener.addheaders.append(('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1'))
    opener.addheaders.append(('Referer', 'http://www.locationary.com/'))
    opener.addheaders.append(('Cookie','site_version=REGULAR'))
    request = urllib2.Request("https://www.locationary.com/index.jsp?ACTION_TOKEN=tile_loginBar_jsp$JspView$LoginAction", data)
    response = opener.open(request)
    page = opener.open("https://www.locationary.com/index.jsp?ACTION_TOKEN=tile_loginBar_jsp$JspView$LoginAction").read()

    h = response.info().headers
    jsid = re.findall(r'Set-Cookie: (.*);', str(h[5]))
    data = urllib.urlencode({"inUserName":"email", "inUserPass":"password"})
    jar = cookielib.FileCookieJar("cookies")
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar))
    opener.addheaders.append(('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1'))
    opener.addheaders.append(('Referer', 'http://www.locationary.com/'))
    opener.addheaders.append(('Cookie','site_version=REGULAR; ' + str(jsid[0])))
    request = urllib2.Request("https://www.locationary.com/index.jsp?ACTION_TOKEN=tile_loginBar_jsp$JspView$LoginAction", data)
    response = opener.open(request)
    page = opener.open(url).read()
    print page

load(URL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [selenium webdriver](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html) from the selenium tool suite uses standard browsers to retrieve the HTML (it's main goal is test automation for web applications), so it is well suited for scrapping javascript-rich applications. It has nice Python bindings.

I tend to use selenium to grab the page source after all ajax stuff is fired and parse it with something like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) (BeautifulSoup copes well with malformed HTML).